# How to bypass the firefox update page when using Selenium?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, junit

I have some selenium tests running on Firefox browser.
unfortunatly, although I take care to create a new profile, I always have the `/firstrun/` page of Firefox showing up when my test start, which is rather annoying, since that page gets it content over the web.

I've tried disabling it the following way

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
    if(!exists) {
        profile.setPreference("signed.applets.codebase_principal_support", true);
        profile.setPreference("capability.principal.codebase.p0.granted", true);
        profile.setPreference("startup.homepage_override_url", "about:blank");
        profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "'ignore'");
```

but it stills shows up.

What can I do to make sure Firefox starts with no page shown ?

Comment: Why the `ignore` value in single quotes? I think it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kiril asks the right question - "Why the single quotes?". Without it works for me.

```
 profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
```

An alternative approach is to load the blank page after the Firefox instance has been created (driver.get("about:blank");)